# load vue-native-websocket in quasar

Tags: vue.js, websocket, quasar

Im trying to load vue-native-websockets in [quasar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-native-websocket-vue3) but Im kind of lost.

I tried to run this as a boot file in quasar:

```
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'

export default async ({ app, router, store, Vue }) => {
   Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'ws://127.0.0.1:5679', { 
     store: store,
     //format: 'json',
     reconnection: true,
     reconnectionAttempts: 5,
     reconnectionDelay: 3000
   })
}
```

and then:

```
this.$socket.send("my value");
```

in a function in my component but I guess I missunderstand the concept. Im pretty new to quasar so a working example would be great indeed ...

I can run this by just creating a connection locally in the component I want to use by putting this in the create method:

```
this.connection = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5679/");
```

and then using that in a method like:

```
this.connection.send("myValue")
```

but the goal is to be able to use the connection in whatever component I like without creating it locally in the create function in that component ...

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

when using:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-native-websocket-vue3

I get this errormessage after implementing it in main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
import  VueNativeSock  from  "vue-native-websocket-vue3" ;

Vue.use( VueNativeSock , 'ws://127.0.0.1:5679' );
```

Errormessage:

> property '$socket' of undefined
> at Object.install (vueNativeWebsocket.common.js?9cca:3701)
> at Function.Vue.use (vue.runtime.esm.js?5593:5107)
> at eval (index.js?a18c:10)
> at Module../src/router/index.js (app.js:1147)   [1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-native-websocket-vue3): https://quasar.dev/

Comment: To be sure, you're using Quasar 1 (= Vue 2) and have a Vuex store set up in your project, right? In that case, your boot file looks fine, except that you can remove the `async`. What happens when you try to `this.$socket.send("my value");` in your component? Is `$socket` undefined or is there some other error?

Comment: hm. actually ````quasar -v```` returns ````2.2.6```` so that actually might be the problem

Comment: I get this errormessage: ````vuex.esm.js?94e4:460 [vuex] unknown mutation type: SOCKET_ONOPEN````